# Recycler View Item Click not working if its put under Swipe Refresh Layout - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, swiperefreshlayout

The recycler view item clicks not working if I put recycler view inside swipe refresh layout. adding the layout below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
    android:text="@string/no_orders_found"
    android:textColor="#616161"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/progressView"
    layout="@layout/layout_progress"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:clickable="false">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_inventory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_15dp"
        android:focusable="true" />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The clicks are working when I remove the swipe refresh layout. How to make recycler view clickable without removing the swipe refresh layout?

More Info: This layout is part of a fragment and the fragment is used as a page of view pager 2. I have two view types in Recycler View adapter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try replace`ConstraintLayout`  with `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_no_order"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
    android:text="@string/no_orders_found"
    android:textColor="#616161"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:visibility="gone"
  
 />

<include
    android:id="@+id/progressView"
    layout="@layout/layout_progress"
    android:visibility="gone"
   />

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    >

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv_inventory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_15dp"
        />
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks,  Replaced the constraint layout with Frame Layout. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `android:paddingVertical="1dp"` to **SwipeRefreshLayout**. recyclerview item started to take clicks

Answer (score 0):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` should not be the blocker for `RecyclerView` item to receive click event, can you also post your `itemClickListener` implementation?

Also, consider using `FrameLayout` for your above layout requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Issue fixed by replacing constraint layout with frame layout.

Answer (score 0):

> Use latest stable version of Constraint Layout. I have same problem because I am using old version.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4"
}
```